# How do I make an object rotate half as fast as another?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a cog that the user can turn to rotate a drawbridge. Currently I have the cog and the drawbridge rotating at the same rate, like so: https://gyazo.com/14426947599095c30ace94a046e9ca21

Here is my current code:

```
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D thingToRotate;
    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);

        Vector2 direction = new Vector2(
            mousePosition.x - transform.position.x,
            mousePosition.y - transform.position.y
         );

        transform.right = direction;
        thingToRotate.transform.up = transform.right;

    }
```

Basically it gets the mouse position, works out the distance between mouse and the drawbridge, then sets the angle based on the vector. The problem is the drawbridge angle is identical to the cogs.

I want it so that when the user turns the cog it only turns the object a little bit, so the user can turn the cog a few times before the drawbridges closes.

I've tried adding to the drawbridges euler angle. I've tried setting the drawbridges rotation to the cog rotation and dividing that rotation by 2.

Is there a function to set an angle based on another angle? Or even a way of setting rotation as a ratio or another?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to calculate the angle between the current orientation and the drag direction, multiply that by your ratio (i.e. 0.5), than convert that into a vector.

```
float ratio = 0.5f;

float ang = ratio * Mathf.Deg2Rad * Vector2.Angle(transform.right, direction);

thingToRotate.transform.up += new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(ang), Mathf.Sin(ang));
```

This would make your code look like:

```
public float ratio = 0.5f;

[SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D thingToRotate;
void OnMouseDrag()
{
    ...

    float ang = ratio * Mathf.Deg2Rad * Vector2.Angle(transform.right, direction);

    thingToRotate.transform.up += new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(ang), Mathf.Sin(ang));

    transform.right = direction;
}
```