# How do I make an object rotate based on another object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a cog that the user can turn to rotate a drawbridge. Currently I have the cog and the drawbridge rotating at the same rate, like so: https://gyazo.com/14426947599095c30ace94a046e9ca21

Here is my current code:

```
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D thingToRotate;
    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);

        Vector2 direction = new Vector2(
            mousePosition.x - transform.position.x,
            mousePosition.y - transform.position.y
         );

        transform.right = direction;
        thingToRotate.transform.up = transform.right;

    }
```

I want it so that when the user turns the cog it only turns the object a little bit, so the user can turn the cog a few times before the drawbridges closes.

I've tried adding to the drawbridges euler angle. I've tried setting the drawbridges rotation to the cog rotation and dividing that rotation by 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make an object rotate half as fast as another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56100692/how-do-i-make-an-object-rotate-half-as-fast-as-another) Please do not post duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set fixed orientations but use the proper methods instead.

- [`Mathf.SignedAngle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.SignedAngle.html) to determine the angle difference between current `transform.right` and the  `direction`
- If using `RigidBody2D` use [`Rigidbody2D.MoveRotatio`n](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MoveRotation.html) instead of setting the rotation through the `Transform` component.

Then I would store the `totalAngle` that was rotated in order to e.g. invoke some event when enough rotation was done.

The `thingToRotate` you simply rotate only to `totalAngle / factor`.

```
// Adjust in the Inspector how often the cog thing has to be turned
// in order to make the thingToRotate perform a full 360° rotation
public float factor = 5f;

private float totalAngle = 0f;

[SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D thingToRotate;
private void OnMouseDrag()
{
    var mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    // this is shorter ;)
    Vector2 direction = (mousePosition - transform.position).normalized;

    // get the angle difference you will move
    var angle = Vector2.SignedAngle(transform.right, direction);

    // rotate yourselve correctly
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * angle);

    // add the rotated amount to the totalangle
    totalAngle += angle;

    // for rigidBodies rather use MoveRotation instead of setting values through
    // the Transform component
    thingToRotate.MoveRotation(totalAngle / factor);
}
```

---

[image]